# Increasing heap by excessive use oft Java ScriptEngine (Jyhton)

Tags: heap-memory, jython

We have a JavaEE application that uses jython to execute some python scripts. By and by the used heapspace gets bigger and bigger until there is no more heapspace left. In a heapdump i can se that there are a lot of Py*-classes.

So i wrote a small test-program:
TestApp

```
public class TestApp {
    private final ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    private HashMap<String, ScriptEngine> scriptEngines = new HashMap<String, ScriptEngine>();
    private final String scriptContainerPath = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int counter = 1;
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("iteration: " + counter);
            TestApp testApp = new TestApp();
            testApp.execute();
            counter++;
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }

    void execute() {
        File scriptContainer = new File(scriptContainerPath);
        File[] scripts = scriptContainer.listFiles();
        if (scripts != null && scripts.length > 0) {
            Arrays.sort(scripts, new Comparator<File>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(File file1, File file2) {
                    return file1.getName().compareTo(file2.getName());
                }
            });

            for (File script : scripts) {

                String engineName = ScriptExecutor.getEngineNameByExtension(script.getName());
                if(!scriptEngines.containsKey(engineName)) {
                    scriptEngines.put(engineName, scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName(engineName));
                }
                ScriptEngine scriptEngine = scriptEngines.get(engineName);

                try {
                    ScriptExecutor scriptExecutor = new ScriptExecutor(scriptEngine, script, null);
                    Boolean disqualify = scriptExecutor.getBooleanScriptValue("disqualify");
                    String reason = scriptExecutor.getStringScriptValue("reason");
                    System.out.println("disqualify: " + disqualify);
                    System.out.println("reason: " + reason);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // cleanup
            for(Map.Entry<String, ScriptEngine> entry : scriptEngines.entrySet()) {
                ScriptEngine engine = entry.getValue();             
                engine.getContext().setErrorWriter(null);
                engine.getContext().setReader(null);
                engine.getContext().setWriter(null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ScriptExecutor

```
public class ScriptExecutor {
    private final static String pythonExtension = "py";
    private final static String pythonEngine = "python";
    private final ScriptEngine scriptEngine;

    public ScriptExecutor(ScriptEngine se, File file, Map<String, Object> keyValues) throws FileNotFoundException, ScriptException {
        scriptEngine = se;
        if (keyValues != null) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : keyValues.entrySet()) {
                scriptEngine.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }
        // execute script
        Reader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new FileReader(file);
            scriptEngine.eval(reader);
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // nothing to do
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Boolean getBooleanScriptValue(String key) {
        // convert Object to Boolean
    }

    public String getStringScriptValue(String key) {
        // convert Object to String
    }

    public static String getEngineNameByExtension(String fileName) {
        String extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

        if (pythonExtension.equalsIgnoreCase(extension)) {
            System.out.println("Found engine " + pythonEngine + " for extension " + extension + ".");
            return pythonEngine;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("No suitable engine found for extension " + extension);
    }
}
```

In the specified directory are 14 python scripts that all look like this:

```
disqualify = True
reason = "reason"
```

I start this program with the following VM-arguments:
-Xrs -Xms16M -Xmx16M -XX:MaxPermSize=32M -XX:NewRatio=3 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=300000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=300000 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -server

These are the arguments our AppServer is running with. Only Xms, Xmx and MaxPermSize are smaller in my testcase.

When I run this application I can see that the CMS Old Gen pool increases to its max size. After that the Par Eden Space pool increases. In addition at any time the ParNewGC does not run anymore. The cleanup part improved the situation but didn't resolve the problem. Has anybody an idea why my heap isn't completly cleaned?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution for my problem: I removed the JSR223 stuff und now use the PythonInterpreter directly.